# Using a Raspberry Pi Motor Driver Board

Tags: ros, raspberrypi, motor-controller, rasbperrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recently purchased a Motor Driver board for my Raspberry Pi (This board:  http://www.waveshare.com/wiki/RPi_Motor_Driver_Board).

In general, when making ROS robots using Raspberry Pi Motor driver boards, is one expected to write code to translate movement-related ROS messages into appropriate GPIO outputs for the motor controller (e.g. to move forward, turn, etc)?  Or is there a "go-to" RPi motor controller module in ROS that most people use?  For context, I understand how to control a simulated ROS robot in Gazebo and how to control a Pioneer P3 robot in real-world using ROS, but I'm unclear how people are controlling RPi motor controllers using ROS.  Any help is appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250693/using-a-raspberry-pi-motor-driver-board/) by [chambana](https://answers.ros.org/users/28837/chambana/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-12-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KevWal](https://answers.ros.org/users/142877/kevwal/) on 2023-03-25**:
Sorry for reopening a really old post, but I am also looking for this, but for ROS2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Some will depend on how you control the motors. If you use PWM then something like the i2cpwm_board package (http://bradanlane.gitlab.io/ros-i2cpwmboard) lets you control standard RC servos directly as well as DC motors via PWM motor controllers. The i2cpwm_board package was developed for RPi projects.

If you need encoders for the drive wheels or for joints, that adds to the solution. (I2cpwm_board does not support encoders.)

---

Originally posted by [suforeman](https://answers.ros.org/users/28415/suforeman/) with karma: 300 on 2016-12-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1